# Windows 10 user account logs in to black screen- other users work fine

Tags: windows, windows-10

Specs: Lenovo y50-70, 8gb ram, 250gb Samsung 830 SSD

I created a new local admin account through the command line and default admin account, but I can't log in to my normal account (linked to my outlook email).

All of my files are there and can be accessed by opening task manager -> right click on a process -> open file location (from within the account, or from explorer in the new account), but my desktop + start menu + general applications don't open.

Comment: Sounds like: 1.There's something wrong with the folder permissions of your account or 2. the registry hive of your account is corrupted. Both of them can be rectified by creating a new account and migrating your files from corrupted account, you can also investigate the root of corruption, but that needs expertise and time, and chances are high that you waste all that time just to realize you have to migrate to a new account.

Comment: How can I transfer installed apps and such that have data/installations that are account-specific? Do I have to re install them?

Comment: No, you don't need to reinstall programs. Read my answer carefully, it's easier than it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UserAccount Migration**

For above 90% of programs, The personalized settings are divided into:

1. Files stored in `%AppData%\APPLICATION NAME` and/or `%LocalAppData%\APPLICATION NAME`

Example:

```
C:\Users\OldUserAccount\AppData\Roaming\Skype
C:\Users\OldUserAccount\AppData\Local\Spotify
```

2. Registry keys that reside under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\APPLICATION NAME` and/or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\APPLICATION NAME` for machine specific settings that apply to all user accounts (which you escape, because you're migrating to the same machine) and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\APPLICATION NAME` That contain user specific settings (which you have to migrate).

Example:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Photoshop
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Internet Download Manager
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Skype
```

You can find the user specific settings in `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%`, `Registry`, or a combination of both. If you're not sure which set migrates the settings and data for your target program (like outlook or office...) just google it or ask here. Chances are high that you find people who have some clue about it. **Don't delete your corrupted account!** As long as it's there, you can go back and pick files and registry keys that you need. Just in case you learned about settings path for another program later.

> **User Specific System Settings**

- Keyboard languages and layouts added to your account:

`HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload`

- All Customizations in Control Panel:

`HKCU\Control Panel`

Including:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\International   \\UserLocale and Regional Settings
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop         \\Desktop Personalizations
HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard        \\Keyboard Settings
HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse           \\Mouse Settings
HKCU\Control Panel\Cursors         \\Cursor Settings
etc...
```

- Windows Explorer Customizations:

`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`

- Startup Applications:

`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

> **How to open/export corrupted user's registry key?**

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Run `regedit`

*Note: Skip to step 7 if you logged on with the corrupted profile*

3. Click on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
4. Click <kbd>File</kbd> and choose <kbd>Load Hive</kbd>
5. Go to `C:\Users\OldUserAccount\NTUSER.DAT` and tap <kbd>Open</kbd>
6. Set the hive name to `OldUserTemp`
7. If logged on with corrupted profile, find keys under `HKCU\SOFTWARE`, if loaded the hive from another account, find keys under `HKLM\OldUserTemp\SOFTWARE`.
8. Right click on each of the program names you need it's settings, and choose <kbd>Export</kbd>. make sure to save it somewhere accessible by other accounts (e.g. Drive D:)
9. You can append all the `.reg` files together to have one unified file. Open files with `notepad`, Copy and append the contents of all other files into one. Ignore `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` line, that's a file header and is needed only once per `.reg` file (at the top). Remove other files.

*Note: Skip this step if you logged on with the corrupted profile*

10. In `notepad`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Fill in `Find what` field with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\OldUserTemp`, and `Replace with` field with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and tap <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

> **How to migrate?**

- Create a new account
- Make sure all the programs you're migrating their settings are closed
- Copy the mentioned folders from corrupted profile to new one
- Double-click the unified `.reg` file you made (in the newly created profile) and approve to import registry keys.
- Not a bad idea to restart windows